# Switch JSON file for a visualisation using a dropdown

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm new to using d3 and JavaScript and I've run into a problem when trying to create a visualisation with multiple JSON files.

I have two JSON files in the same format but containing different data. I have written a code which produces two line graphs from the JSON file, which works with either file. What I want to do is use a dropdown menu to switch between the files so that I can alternate which data is shown.

I'm hoping that someone has a working example which they can share or can talk me through how to do this?

My code as it stands is (you can see that I'm using the file All.json and i want to be able to reference a different file using the dropdown):

```js
var h = 200;
var w = 400;
var padding = 40;

function buildline(ds) {
  //scales
  var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([
      d3.min(ds.timeSeries, function(d) {
        return d.year
      }),
      d3.max(ds.timeSeries, function(d) {
        return d.year
      })
    ])
    .range([padding, w - padding]);

  var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(ds.timeSeries, function(d) {
      return d.trips;
    }) + padding])
    .range([h - padding, 10]);

  var yAxisGen = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left");
  var xAxisGen = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient("bottom").tickFormat(d3.format("0000"));

  var lineFun = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) {
      return xScale(d.year);
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return yScale(d.trips);
    })
    .interpolate("linear");

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr({
    width: w,
    height: h
  })

  var yAxis = svg.append("g").call(yAxisGen)
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + ", 0)");

  var xAxis = svg.append("g").call(xAxisGen)
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + (h - padding) + ")");

  var viz = svg.append("path")
    .attr({
      d: lineFun(ds.timeSeries),
      "stroke": "green",
      "stroke-width": 2,
      "fill": "none"
    });

}

function showHeader(ds) {
  d3.select("body").append("h1")
    .text(ds.category + " (2002-2013)");
}

d3.json("All.json", function(error, data) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log(data);
  }

  data.contents.forEach(function(ds) {
    console.log(ds);
    showHeader(ds);
    buildline(ds);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<p>Choose Mode
  <select id="mode-option">
    <option = value ="All">All modes</option>
    <option = value ="Other">Other</option>
  </select>
</p>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Why is there an equals (=) sign after the `OPTION` tag name?

Answer (score 0):

Your select doesn't need the additional equal sign

```
<select id="mode-option">
    <option value="All">All modes</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
```

And then assign an event listener to determine the file based on the selection

```
document.getElementById('mode-option').addEventListener('change', function () {
    var file = this.value + '.json';
    d3.json(file, function (error, data) { ...
});
```

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks for the help, I've now got the dropdown working. Now got a separate issue with the script but i'll post that as a new question. Thanks again!